# Reading and writing binary data from one to another file

Tags: c#, encoding, streamwriter

I'm reading a binary file and writing to another file in CP 437 format by skipping few lines. But the output file size is increased than the original file and also data is corrupted. Any help to identify the issue.

```
        StreamReader sStreamReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Denesh\Input.txt");
        string AllData = sStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] rows = AllData.Split(",".ToCharArray());

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(TransLog, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(437));
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outFile, false);
        int num = 0;
        int count = 0;

            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string tlogline = streamReader.ReadLine();

                if (rows[count] == Convert.ToString(num))
                {
                    ++count;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++num;
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(tlogline, streamReader.CurrentEncoding);
                }
            }

        fileStream.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Adding filestream for streamwriter solves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding filestream for streamwriter solves the issue. Thanks.